# this.setState() won't execute with a specific object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, setstate

I can not figure out what is going on, and hoping some fresh eyes will help. This worked fine for days, and now it's not, with no change.

I have 2 objects - the `gamesImages` and `gamePlay`. `gamePlay` is a record including multiple join tables. `gameImages` is 10 different records.

I make a call:

```
matchingGameApiHelper.getGamePlay(this.props.currentUser.authToken, data)
  .then(data => {
      let gameData = data.data
      console.log(gameData.data.gameImages)
      //output -> (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

      this.setState({
        activeGame: true,
        room: room,
        gamePlay: gameData.data.gamePlay,
        gameImages: gameData.data.gameImages,
      }, () => console.log('setState is done'))
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

When the `gameImages: gameData.data.gameImages`  line is removed, it works fine. With it in, it doesn't update state, and doesn't throw an error. It basically just stops and doesn't run anything after it. I also tried saving just one like: `gameImages: gameData.data.gameImages[0]`, and that works fine.

UPDATE: here is initial state

```
this.state = {
  activeGame: '',
  room: '',
  gamePlay: [],
  gameImages: [],
 }
```

I've also tried `gameImages: {},`

UPDATE2 here is expanded output for gameImages:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, image_file_name: "adult-afro-beautiful-1858175.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:44:54.382Z", …}
1: {id: 2, image_file_name: "adult-asian-blue-936593.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:46:41.291Z", …}
2: {id: 3, image_file_name: "adult-attractive-beautiful-1197132_(1).jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:47:06.869Z", …}
3: {id: 4, image_file_name: "adult-attractive-casual-247885.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:47:41.877Z", …}
4: {id: 5, image_file_name: "adult-beach-casual-736716.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:47:55.862Z", …}
5: {id: 6, image_file_name: "adult-beard-cute-1250426.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:48:15.063Z", …}
6: {id: 7, image_file_name: "adult-beautiful-brunette-1181686.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:48:46.868Z", …}
7: {id: 8, image_file_name: "adult-beautiful-cute-1520760.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:49:29.462Z", …}
8: {id: 9, image_file_name: "adult-beautiful-cute-1895160.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:49:47.166Z", …}
9: {id: 10, image_file_name: "adult-blue-boy-1438275.jpg", exchange_id: 58, premium: false, created_at: "2019-04-30T22:50:10.189Z", …}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and here is the original data returned:

```
data:
  gameImages: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  gamePlay: {id: 482, player_one: 32, player_two: null, room: "LEX305", exchange_id: 58, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: That is just weird. Any chance that you are calling this.setState() somewhere else at the same time of this call?

Comment: Nope - when it hits that line, nothing else is executed. I updated the question to say that if I save just 1 record `gameImages: gameData.data.gameImages[0]` it works fine, it's when I'm trying to save all of them, like it doesn't like the format or something?

Comment: What type is gameImages declared as (if you're using typescript and do that), and what's its initial value set to in the constructor?

Comment: @HammerN'Songs see update at bottom of question

Comment: Does the 'setState is done' show up?

Also, can you add a print after the setState call to see if execution goes after that?

Comment: If gamePlay is a single object/record, it should be set to `{}` instead of `[]`, and if gameImages is a list of objects, it should need to be set to `[]`. But that still shouldn't be causing what you're seeing. Is there a chance that something that uses gameImages, expects to see one object instead of a list of objects, and the system is actually failing there?

Comment: No, `setState is done` doesn't print, and i console log right after the setState() which also doesn't execute with gameImages is present. I feel like it has something to do with the type - it being an object containing other objects? does it need to be an array of objects instead, or something like that?

Comment: Hmm - the `//output -> (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` means that it's an array of objects, which sounds like what you want. Maybe. And plain javascript doesn't have any checks for type mismatches, so if it's failing due to gameImage's format, it'd be at the place where gameImages is used after being set. Can you confirm that the output of that first console log is exactly what you have commented out there? It'd make sense for things to break if gameImages was for some reason formatted in a non-json fashion (like `{{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id 3}}`).

Comment: @HammerN'Songs I added another update with an expanded view of the objects.

Comment: Well, there goes that idea. That is weird. Just curious, but what happens if you setState gameImages to `[]`, or `[gameData.data.gameImages[0]]`? Since you said it didn't die (although I assume didn't work correctly either) with `gameData.data.gameImages[0]`.

Comment: @HammerN'Songs both work fine, and successfully update state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194265/discussion-between-hammernsongs-and-gwalshington).

Comment: Is `matchingGameApiHelper` an API call? If so, setting up logic against `data`, which could be in an error, is going to cause unpredictable behavior. Checking if the response is ok and has `data` would be conventional and also aid with debugging this particular issue.

Comment: @JakeWorth what does that mean? I put above what 'data' is. What is your proposed solution?

Comment: @gwalshington I'm interested in this, but it's hard to trust what `data` is every time (despite the console.log shared) because the response of an API can change even if the code stays the same. The code assumes success and a very specific shape (including `data.data.data.gameImages`). If you could provide a code sandbox (understanding that you may not be able to) that might help move this question forward.